# How to hide Views from screenshots/screen recordings in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

SwiftUI has a `SecureField` text field which doesn't show anything typed into it when viewed from screen recordings or screenshots. Similarly, iOS 15 is going to have a `.privacySensitive()` modifier that removes the View from widgets and such. Does anyone have any idea on how to implement Views like this? I want a View which blurs itself when it's contained in screen recordings, screenshots, app widgets, multitasking menu (so they can't cheat the system) etc.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this effect would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** You can tell if someone has opened the multitasking menu by subscribing to `NotifcationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActive, perform: { _ in })`. However I still haven't been able to figure out the others

**Edit 2:** I also found that subscribing to `UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification` tells you if screen recording is active. Still stuck on screenshots and widgets

Answer (score 1):

Today, in iOS 17 the textfield hack is still working.
To summarize - add your view in the first subview of the secured textfield

```
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    
    frameView.addSubview(textField)
    textField.edgesToSuperview()
    textField.subviews.first?.addSubview(viewToHide)
    qrCodeImageView.edgesToSuperview()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I bring good news. I had a solution already implemented for "science" purposes. As already mentioned in one of the answers above you can use the SecureField trick to accomplish the task of hiding a screenshot or recording of a View. I'm gonna share with you a View that you can easily use to embed any other SwiftUI View to be hidden from unwanted screenshots or screen recordings:

```
struct ScreenshotPreventView<Content: View>: View {
    
    var content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    // MARK: - UI
    @State private var hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>?
    
    var body: some View {
        _ScreenshotPreventHelper(hostingController: $hostingController)
            .overlay(
                GeometryReader {
                    let size = $0.size
                    
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(key: SizeKey.self, value: size)
                        .onPreferenceChange(SizeKey.self, perform: { value in
                            if value != .zero {
                                /// Create Hosting Controller with Size
                                if hostingController == nil {
                                    hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: content)
                                    hostingController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
                                    hostingController?.view.tag = 1009
                                    hostingController?.view.frame = .init(origin: .zero, size: size)
                                } else {
                                    /// Sometimes the view size may update. In that case we update the UIView Size
                                    hostingController?.view.frame = .init(origin: .zero, size: size)
                                }
                            }
                        })
                }
            )
    }
    
}

fileprivate struct SizeKey: PreferenceKey {
    
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
    
}

fileprivate struct _ScreenshotPreventHelper<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let secureField = UITextField()
        secureField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        if let textLayoutView = secureField.subviews.first {
            return textLayoutView
        }
        return UIView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        /// Adding hosting view as a Subview to the TextLayout View
        if let hostingController, !uiView.subviews.contains(where: { $0.tag == 1009 }) {
            /// Adding hosting controller for one time
            uiView.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        }
    }
    
}
```

You can use it like a any other View in SwiftUI:

```
ScreenshotPreventView {
    // Place here the view you want to protect
}
```

Let me know if this worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure if you can hide screenshots because `UIApplication` only has a `.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification` Notification Name. If you are trying to do it manually rather than using iOS 15s `.privacySensitive()`, you can overlay a `View` over the entire app. To do this, as you stated you could use the `UIApplication.willResignActive` to overlay such a view in the **Multitasking menu**.

To achieve this however you need to get the `window` and add the subview to it as follows

```
let currentWindow: UIWindow? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
currentWindow?.addSubview(myOverlayView)
```

For the screenshot problem, like I stated above, Swift only has a `.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification` and no `.userWillTakeScreenshotNotification`. So the best bet is to delete the last image by listening to the screenshot notification. You can see how to delete the last photo of the gallery [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982064/how-to-delete-an-image-from-photolibrary-after-i-pick-it-up-using-uiimagepickerc/29982133). This should provide the `delete for all` feature Whatsapp seems to use. Given that, you will still have to provide access to the gallery

This should give you something similar to the snapchat app. **This code is not tested**

Comment: Yeah I managed to figure out the multitasking and screen recording bits. I'm still figuring out the screenshot one. Let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: I think the image will still be in "Recently Deleted". Can we delete images from there as well?