# How to detect a screenshot on iOS in order to block the content (similar to WhatsApp View Once photos)

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot, whatsapp

I am trying to mimic what WhatsApp is doing when taking a screenshot of View Once photos, which is to add an overlay to the content that is sensitive (see image below)

From what I see in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622966-userdidtakescreenshotnotificatio), we only get a notification *after* the screenshot is taken.

I wonder how they did it to detect when the screenshot is taken to add this overlay

[image: whatsapp blocks sensitive content when taking a screenshot]

Finally, if the user tries to record the screen, I think [this notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/2921652-captureddidchangenotification) is enough to add the overlay, however I don't know how to do it when they take a screenshot.

Comment: You could use a solution I posted here, i think it's pretty handy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68421711/how-to-hide-views-from-screenshots-screen-recordings-in-swiftui/77841290#77841290

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent screen capture in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution is to use this extension to block the screenshots.

```
extension UIView {
    
    func makeSecure() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let field = UITextField()
            field.isSecureTextEntry = true
            self.addSubview(field)
            field.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            field.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            self.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(field.layer)
            field.layer.sublayers?.first?.addSublayer(self.layer)
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
let yourView = UIView()
yourView.makeSecure()
```

It will prevent the user from taking a screenshot or recording the specific view.

If you need to show a placeholder when a user tries to screenshot or record then check this repo.

**Sample code:** https://github.com/kuttz/SecureYourView

**Result:**
https://github.com/kuttz/DemosAndScreenShots/blob/main/SecureYourView/Demo.gif

Comment: Not working at all

Comment: Did you try the sample project?

Comment: Yes, it does not work and crashes after a while due to an infinite loop. I think it's because you are adding the `field`'s layer as a subview of the `self` and then the `self`'s layer as a sublayer of the `field`

Comment: Above SecureYourView is working well for me

Answer (score 0):

I worked on an app where securing chat content was a requirement. After R&D, I concluded that preventing screen capture in an iOS app is not directly supported by the iOS operating system. However, we can customize our code to achieve the desired result.

As a solution, I created [ScreenShield](https://github.com/JayantBadlani/ScreenShield), an iOS library designed to secure content by blocking screenshots and screen recordings. It provides a simple solution to protect your app's content. I hope it proves helpful for others facing the same challenge.

[ScreenShield for ios UIKit/SwiftUI](https://github.com/JayantBadlani/ScreenShield)

HOW TO USE:

Add the following line to your Podfile and run pod install:

```
pod 'ScreenShield'
```

UIKIT EXAMPLE:

```
import UIKit
import ScreenShield

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
        
        // Protect ScreenShot
        ScreenShield.shared.protect(view: self.view)
        
        // Protect Screen-Recording
        ScreenShield.shared.protectFromScreenRecording()
    }
}
```

SWIFTUI EXAMPLE:

```
    import SwiftUI
import ScreenShield

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .protectScreenshot() // Protect the view
            .onAppear {
                ScreenShield.shared.protectFromScreenRecording() // Protect Screen-Recording
            }
    }
}
```